# Why is Decimal('0') > 9999.0 True in Python?

Tags: python, comparison, types, operators, logic

This is somehow related to my question [Why is ''>0 True in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384078/why-is-0-true-in-python)

In Python 2.6.4:

```
>> Decimal('0') > 9999.0
True
```

From the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384078/why-is-0-true-in-python/2384090#2384090) to my original question I understand that when comparing objects of different types in Python 2.x the types are ordered by their name. But in this case:

```
>> type(Decimal('0')).__name__ > type(9999.0).__name__
False
```

Why is `Decimal('0') > 9999.0 == True` then?

UPDATE: I usually work on Ubuntu (Linux 2.6.31-20-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 8 09:05:19 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux, Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Dec  7 2009, 18:45:15) [GCC 4.4.1] on linux2). On Windows (WinXP Professional SP3, Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Nov 3 2009, 13:23:17) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32) my original statement works differently:

```
>> Decimal('0') > 9999.0
False
```

I even more puzzled now. %-(

Comment: I don't get the same results for your first statement. On mine it comes up as False. I do get the same result for your second statement though. I am also using Python 2.6.4.

Comment: @Justin that leaves me even more puzzled as I triple checked and it does return `True`

Comment: using python 3.1.1, the first statement gives (after importing Decimal): `TypeError: unorderable types: Decimal() > float()`

Comment: @Justin I checked again on Windows box and it returned `False` %-(

Comment: I'm getting true for the first statement.
  Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Dec  7 2009, 18:43:55)
  [GCC 4.4.1] on linux2
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more     information.
  >>> from decimal import *
  >>> Decimal('0')>9999.0
True

Comment: @Justin, parxier: `Decimal('0') > 9999 == False` and `Decimal('0') > 9999.0 == True` on Python 2.6.2 64-bit, Win7.

Comment: Well, at least you have learned not to depend on this type of thing in Production code :)

Comment: @parxier It's perfectly related to the question Alex answered before.

Comment: Since the statement is useless and returns inconsistent results, what's the question?  Is the question "why does an expression with no possible meaning return a result?"  Or is it "why does a expression with no possible meaning return inconsistent results?"

Comment: @S.Lott: It is not useless, I want to compare two valid numbers. Why can I compare ints and floats, Decimals and ints, but not Decimals and floats?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the decimal module does not compare against any type except long, int, and Decimal.  In all other cases, decimal silently returns the "not something it knows about object" as greater.  You can see this behavior in the _convert_other() function of decimal.py

Silly, silly Decimal class.

*Oh, see http://bugs.python.org/issue2531 as well.*

So, here is what happens:

- The interpreter calls the `Decimal.__gt__` comparison function.
- `Decimal.__gt__` calls `Decimal._convert_other` to convert the incoming float to a Decimal.
- `Decimal._convert_other` doesn't understand floats.  The implementation down in `Decimal._convert_other` 
  explicitly checks for `long`, `int`, and `Decimal` types of the operand.  Yes, this is 
  a bug, in that unexpected library implementations cause bugs further down the line.  It
  would be cleaner to do the right thing or even just through a `TypeException`.  Instead
  it throughs the same `NotImplemented` that would happen comparing a Decimal to, say,
  a hash of Employee records.
- A few other comparison operations are tried.  Comparison gives up.
- The default comparison, down in CPython's Objects/object.c/default_3way_compare get called.
- In Python 3, this rightly barfs.  In Python 2, it compares the id() functions.
- On Windows, a case insensitive comparison is used (sort of).   On modern systems, a 
  case sensitive comparison is used.
- So you get different results.

Are we there yet?

Comment: Tx for setting me right, so I deleted my (misleading) answer and +1'd yours in gratitude;-).

Comment: @charles: Why then it works differently on different platforms?

Comment: No clue.  I don't have Windows.  Try pulling up the _convert_other() on both and comparing them.

Comment: @Charles Merram: This isn't quite right.  Decimal doesn't return the "not something it knows about object" as greater:  it returns `NotImplemented`.  Since the float side of the comparison also returns `NotImplemented`, Python falls back to the default rules it applies when neither operand knows how to compare with the other;  this ends up effectively comparing `id(float)` and `id(Decimal)`, so the result just depends on the addresses in memory of the `float` and `Decimal` types (which explains platform differences).  The gory details are in `default_3way_compare` in Objects/object.c.

Comment: Hmm.. Sounds reasonable and I'll look at it.

Comment: @Mark: your comment **is** the answer to my question, how can I accept it?

Comment: @Mark: I extracted your comments as an accepted answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
def __gt__(self, other, context=None):
    other = _convert_other(other)
    if other is NotImplemented:
        return other
    ans = self._compare_check_nans(other, context)
    if ans:
        return False
    return self._cmp(other) > 0


def _convert_other(other, raiseit=False):
    """Convert other to Decimal.

    Verifies that it's ok to use in an implicit construction.
    """
    if isinstance(other, Decimal):
        return other
    if isinstance(other, (int, long)):
        return Decimal(other)
    if raiseit:
        raise TypeError("Unable to convert %s to Decimal" % other)
    return NotImplemented
```