# Easy python program

Tags: python

The user is prompted for a file, which in this case is 'histogram.txt'. The program takes each score in the text file and makes a histogram out of all the grades in the file, organizing them so that the user can see how many of each range there are. I wrote out a very simple code:

```
filename = raw_input('Enter filename of grades: ')

histogram10 = 0
histogram9 = 0
histogram8 = 0
histogram7 = 0
histogram6 = 0
histogram5 = 0
histogram4 = 0
histogram3 = 0
histogram2 = 0
histogram1 = 0
histogram0 = 0

for score in open(filename):
    if score >= 100:
        histogram10 = histogram10 + 1
    elif score >= 90: 
        histogram9 = histogram9 + 1
    elif score >= 80:
        histogram8 = histogram8 + 1
    elif score >= 70:
        histogram7 = histogram7 + 1
    elif score >= 60:
        histogram6 = histogram6 + 1
    elif score >= 50:
        histogram5 = histogram5 + 1
    elif score >= 40:
        histogram4 = histogram4 + 1
    elif score >= 30:
        histogram3 = histogram3 + 1
    elif score >= 20:
        histogram2 = histogram2 + 1
    elif score >= 10:
        histogram1 = histogram1 + 1
    elif score >= 0:
        histogram0 = histogram0 + 1

print    
print 'Grade Distribution'
print '------------------'
print '100     :',('*' * histogram10)
print '90 - 99 :',('*' * histogram9)
print '80 - 89 :',('*' * histogram8)
print '70 - 79 :',('*' * histogram7)
print '60 - 69 :',('*' * histogram6)
print '50 - 59 :',('*' * histogram5)
print '40 - 49 :',('*' * histogram4)
print '30 - 39 :',('*' * histogram3)
print '20 - 29 :',('*' * histogram2)
print '10 - 19 :',('*' * histogram1)
print '00 - 09 :',('*' * histogram0)
```

however whenever i run the program, all twenty grades get recorded onto the >= 100
like this:

```
100    : ********************
90-99  : 
80-89  :
```

etc.
... How do I make it so that the program puts the stars in the correct places?

Comment: Always step 1: make sure the data that is getting into the program is correct.

Comment: you are comparing string with numbers...

Comment: A little tip: Instead of having 11 different variables for the histogram, you could use a list and calculate the index, e.g. `histogram[min(100, score) / 10] += 1`. The `min` is to put all scores above 100 in the same slot. For more general data, like counting the number of words in a text, you could use a dictionary.

Comment: [Any number is always less than any string in Python 2.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969552/why-does-4-3-return-true-in-python-2)

Comment: One liner just for fun `any(__import__('sys').stdout.write('<= {} \t {}\n'.format(i * 10 + 10, '*' * num))
    for i, num in ((k, len(list(g)))
        for k, g in __import__('itertools').groupby(
            sorted(int(score.strip())
                for score in open(raw_input('Enter filename of grades: '))),
                    key = lambda score: (score - 1) / 10)))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert `score` to int before comparing.

```
score = int(score)  # convert to int
if score >= 100:
    histogram10 = histogram10 + 1
# other cases
```

If you have blank lines in input file then you have to add necessary check before converting to int. Also instead of ten different variables you can easily use a list.

Comment: thank you for this i also appreciate the advice. im still very new at compsci :P if you don't mind can you explain how to use a list with this?

Comment: Please go through the list tutorial http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists. For `histogram0` you can use `l[0]`, for `histogram1` you can use `l[1]` and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Data read from a file is a string. Convert it to an integer first by passing it to `int()`.

```
>>> int('25')
25
```