# Why does the following short script in Python disregard the condition in "if"?

Tags: python, if-statement

I want it to give 'Number of donuts: many' when the argument is more than 10 and 'Number of donuts: ' when the argument is count<10. But it always gives me 'Number of donuts: many'

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6 -tt
import sys
def donuts(count):
  if count < 10:
    x = str(count)
  else:
    x = 'many'
  print 'Number of donuts: ' + x

def main():
  donuts(sys.argv[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969552/why-does-4-3-return-true-in-python-2

Comment: Hint: What do you expect to happen when I run `donuts.py bananas`? Why? What actually does happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sys.argv` will only contain strings, even if you provide integers as arguments, so for example if you called this as `python donuts.py 4`, then `sys.argv[1]` would be `'4'` and you would attempt the comparison `'4' < 10` when you actually want `4 < 10`.

So first, try to convert `sys.argv[1]` to an int:

```
def main():
    donuts(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

You may want to add some error handling as well, in case an argument is not provided or it is not an integer:

```
def main():
    try:
        donuts(int(sys.argv[1]))
    except IndexError:
        print 'Missing argument'
    except ValueError:
        print 'Invalid argument'
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! It was very instructive for a new python user like me.

Answer (score 5):

`count` is a string. Try `count = int(count)`

Answer (score 3):

You should convert count to an int before comparing it to 10:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6 -tt
import sys
def donuts(count):
    if int(count) < 10:
        x = count
    else:
        x = 'many'
    print 'Number of donuts: %s' % x

def main():
    donuts(sys.argv[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try converting the `count` parameter to an int for the comparison:

```
if int (count) < 10:
  x = str (count)
else:
  x = 'many'
```

Because you're passing in a string argument for the `count` parameter, the comparison is failing.

Answer (score 3):

You don't take the input in as an integer to begin with.

Change:

```
def main():
  donuts(sys.argv[1])
```

to:

```
def main():
  donuts(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

You will run into an issue if they put in a string or decimal instead of a numerical value, though.