# Why a string in always "greater than" a number?

Tags: python

I just noticed that Python allows you to compare a string value with a number:

```
>>> '10' > 1000
True
>>> 'a' > 1000
True
>>> 'a' > -1000
True
```

Why is any string always greater than any number?

Comment: You're comparing two different types that do not have any meaningful comparison, so it is up to the interpreter's implementation, I believe.

Comment: If you're asking "Why did Python choose this rule" rather than "What is the rule", [Alex Martelli's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2384139/908494) on a different dup of the question is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @abarnert excellent explanation on the why it came to be so, and why this raises an error in Python 3, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2, [§5.3 - Comparisons](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) says:

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types and different string types, never compare equal; **such objects are ordered consistently but arbitrarily** (so that sorting a heterogeneous array yields a consistent result). Furthermore, some types (for example, file objects) support only a degenerate notion of comparison where any two objects of that type are unequal. Again, such objects are ordered arbitrarily but consistently. The `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` operators will raise a TypeError exception when any operand is a complex number.

In Python 3, [§4.3 - Comparisons](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) says:

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types, never compare equal. Furthermore, some types (for example, function objects) support only a degenerate notion of comparison where any two objects of that type are unequal. **The `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` operators will raise a TypeError exception** when comparing a complex number with another built-in numeric type, **when the objects are of different types that cannot be compared**, or in other cases where there is no defined ordering.

Comment: It's probably worth adding the "CPython implementation detail" below that as well, which explains why he sees that particular "consistent but arbitrary" ordering. (Although it isn't 100% complete; it doesn't explain that `None` is always less than anything else, and numeric types are always less than anything non-`None`, or what "numeric" means, or the rules for dealing with pathological subclasses of built-in numeric types, or… But the only place you'll find more explanation is in the source code.)