# Why do empty string and None evaluate differently?

Tags: python, evaluation

Why do those two evaluate differently?

```
In [34]: a = ''

In [35]: if a or a >=0:
    print 'y'
    ....:     
y

In [36]: a = None

In [37]: if a or a >=0:
    print 'y'
    ....:
```

I thought an empty string also evaluates to None (I know they are not the same)? Or is it just falsy and thus evaluates to 0 (which then evaluates to None if tested like `if a: do something`)?

Comment: I missed where you get confused. In the first example? It print `y` because of the `>= 0` part.

Comment: I was not expecting the first example to print anything.

Comment: It's because of how string vs int comparison works. The `if a` part doesn't kick in because, as you say, an empty string and `None` is not the same thing.

Comment: Related: [How does Python compare string and int?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3270680/142637)

Comment: [Even more related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2384078/645270). The short answer is: why would you ever want to do such a comparison? It's even fixed in python 3

Comment: Thanks for the link, indeed very related. I test for empty strings often like `if not x:` instead of `if x !=''`. So i was just adding a condition and then got confused...

Comment: @LarsVegas That makes sense. The condition you added kind of doesn't :)

Comment: You should use `if a and a >= 0` if you expected the test to behave the same for both values. Or switch to Python 3, where strings and integers are not orderable relative to one another.

Comment: On Python 3 you'll get `TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()`.

Comment: @LarsVegas : using `if not x` instead of `if x != ''` is the pythonic idiom (the empty string being False in a boolean context). Your problem comes from comparing oranges and bananas - in this case, either a string or `None` with an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in CPython `int` comes before `string`

from [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

> CPython implementation detail: Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.

so:

```
>>> '1' > 1
True
```