# Python line.split only acts on one line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of highscores (saved in a text file as the score, space, name (no commas)). However, when I go to retrieve the data, it appears only the first line is read.

```
for line in previous_scores:
    data = line.split()
    current_data = data[0]
    if int(current_data) > highscore:
        highscore = current_data
        highscore_names = [data[1]]
    elif int(current_data) == highscore:
        highscore_names.append(data[1])
```

For example, with the data below:

```
2 James
3 Anna
5 Emily
```

It would return the highscore as James, with his score being 2.

If my code is wrong could you please tell me what is wrong, and if your really awesome fix it. I don't mind if there is a better way to do this.

Edit:
The file is opened with:

```
previous_scores = open("Scores.txt", "a+")
```

Edit 2:
I added some extra lines on the end, and updated the code for testing to the following:

```
for line in previous_scores:
data = line.split()
current_data = data[0]
print "1 " + data[0]
print "2 " + current_data
if int(current_data) > highscore:
    print "3 " + current_data
    highscore = current_data
    highscore_names = [data[1]]
elif int(current_data) == highscore:
    print "4 " + current_data
    highscore_names.append(data[1])
elif int(current_data) < highscore:
    print "5 " + current_data
```

The first score always returns 1, 2 and 3, and then all other scores return 1, 2 and 5.

Comment: how you opening the file and reading, can you show that

Comment: We need to know what is in previous_scores - IE how you got it.  We also need to know what is the initial value of highscore.  Please see http://stackoverflow/help/mvce .

Comment: You can also save you and us a lot of trouble by putting print statements after each line, to prove to yourself that what you think the value of each "thing" is is indeed what it is.   By the time you've done that, you'll likely have solved your problem.

Comment: And... what is the meaning of your title?   Are you really expecting line.split to return more than one line?  I dont think so.  line.split is returning strings from a single line.

Comment: If so how do you line.split multiple lines???

Comment: here james has 2 score how it is high score, emily has 5??

Comment: And http://stackoverflow/help/mvce is a broken link.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams i think uou want lowest score right??

Comment: @Hackaholic no, i want the highest. i have a quiz and at the end the user gets a score, in a separate section of the code this is then written to the highscores file. i then want to find the highest scores from this list of scores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    if int(current_data) > highscore:
        highscore = current_data
```

Here you convert the current highscore to a number, but store it as an unconverted string. Next loop you are comparing the next highscore as a number to the previously saved string.

I don't know what comparing number > string does in Python, but it's legal syntax and returns *False*, so you never save a higher highscore after the very first one.

Edit: Now I know, and it's interesting but irrelevant for this answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3270689/478656 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2384139/478656

Comment: Thanks, so how do I fix the code. You don't need to do it for me just tell me how, or if its quicker you can fix it. Thanks.