# What does x[x < 2] = 0 mean in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I came across some code with a line similar to

```
x[x<2]=0
```

Playing around with variations, I am still stuck on what this syntax does.

Examples:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> x[x<2]
1
>>> x[x<3]
1
>>> x[x>2]
2
>>> x[x<2]=0
>>> x
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: it never makes sense to do this with a list.

Comment: This only makes sense with NumPy arrays or similar objects, which behave completely differently from the behavior in your experiments or the list-based behavior explained in either answer.

Comment: Note, this does not work in Python 3. Types are only able to be compared when the comparison makes sense. In Python 3 this example throws `TypeError: unorderable types: list() < int()`.

Comment: Too little information. Should've mentioned that the array is a numpy array.

Comment: I'm shocked this got so many upvotes (though it is indeed a good question for SO format).

Comment: Are you sure it was a list? This would also be a valid way to access `True` or `False` keys in a dictionary.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan You would access a dictionary by comparing the_same_ dictionary with a number?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

This only makes sense with **[NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) arrays**. The behavior with lists is useless, and specific to Python 2 (not Python 3). You may want to double-check if the original object was indeed a NumPy array (see further below) and not a list.

But in your code here, x is a simple list.

Since

```
x < 2
```

is False
i.e 0, therefore

`x[x<2]` is `x[0]`

`x[0]` gets changed.

Conversely, `x[x>2]` is `x[True]` or `x[1]`

So, `x[1]` gets changed.

**Why does this happen?**

The rules for comparison are:

1. When you order two strings or two numeric types the ordering is done in the expected way (lexicographic ordering for string, numeric ordering for integers).
2. When you order a numeric and a non-numeric type, the numeric type comes first.
3. When you order two incompatible types where neither is numeric, they are ordered by the alphabetical order of their typenames:

So, we have the following order

numeric < list < string < tuple

See the accepted answer for *[How does Python compare string and int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int)*.

**If x is a NumPy array**, then the syntax makes more sense because of **boolean array indexing**. In that case, `x < 2` isn't a boolean at all; it's an array of booleans representing whether each element of `x` was less than 2. `x[x < 2] = 0` then selects the elements of `x` that were less than 2 and sets those cells to 0. See *[Indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)*.

```
>>> x = np.array([1., -1., -2., 3])
>>> x < 0
array([False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> x[x < 0] += 20   # All elements < 0 get increased by 20
>>> x
array([  1.,  19.,  18.,   3.]) # Only elements < 0 are affected
```

Comment: Given that the OP specifically says "I came across some code like this...", I think your answer describing numpy boolean indexing is very useful - might be worth pointing out that if the OP scrolls up the code they looked at, they'll almost certainly see an `import` for numpy.

Comment: Still an overly clever way to do it, surely? (As compared with, say, `[0 if i < 2 else i for i in x]`.) Or is this encouraged style in Numpy?

Comment: @TimPederick: Using list comprehensions with NumPy is a pretty bad idea. It's dozens to hundreds of times slower, it doesn't work with arbitrary-dimensional arrays, it's easier to get the element types screwed up, and it creates a list instead of an array. Boolean array indexing is completely normal and expected in NumPy.

Comment: @TimPederick In addition to the performance hit it's also likely that whoever wrote the code intended to keep using a numpy array. `x[x<2]` will return a numpy array,  whereas `[0 if i<2 else i for i in x]` returns a list. This is because `x[x<2]` is an indexing operation (referred to in numpy/scipy/pandas as a slicing operation due to the ability to mask data), whereas the list comprehension is a new object definition. See [NumPy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Answer (score 45):

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> x<2
False
>>> x[False]
1
>>> x[True]
2
```

The bool is simply converted to an integer. The index is either 0 or 1.

Comment: You might mention that `x` and `2` are ["*ordered consistently but arbitrarily*"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) and that the ordering might change in different Python implementations.

Comment: Yepp. python3: http://ideone.com/1Cw4gb and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int

Comment: I would also add that this is a *clever* way of doing things and should in my opinion be avoided. Do it explicitly - the fact that OP had to ask this question supports my point.

Comment: can you add more details, why `x<2 == false`?

Comment: `bool` is not converted to an integer, a `bool` in Python **is an integer**

Comment: Just to clarify @AnttiHaapala's statement for anyone else that comes along, `bool` *is a subclass* of `int`.

Answer (score 14):

The original code in your question works only in Python 2. If `x` is a `list` in Python 2, the comparison `x < y` is `False` if `y` is an `int`eger. This is because it does not make sense to compare a list with an integer. However in Python 2, if the operands are not comparable, the comparison is based in CPython on the [**alphabetical ordering of the names of the types**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons); additionally **all numbers come first in mixed-type comparisons**. This is not even spelled out in the documentation of CPython 2, and different Python 2 implementations could give different results. That is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] < 2` evaluates to `False` because `2` is a number and thus "smaller" than a `list` in CPython. This mixed comparison was eventually [deemed to be too obscure a feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2384139/918959), and was removed in Python 3.0.

---

Now, the result of `<` is a `bool`; and [`bool` is a *subclass* of `int`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/):

```
>>> isinstance(False, int)
True
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
>>> False == 0
True
>>> True == 1
True
>>> False + 5
5
>>> True + 5
6
```

So basically you're taking the element 0 or 1 depending on whether the comparison is true or false.

---

If you try the code above in Python 3, you will get `TypeError: unorderable types: list() < int()` due to [a change in Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons):

> **Ordering Comparisons**
>
> Python 3.0 has simplified the rules for ordering comparisons:
>
> The ordering comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `>=`, `>`) raise a `TypeError` exception when the operands don’t have a meaningful natural ordering. Thus, expressions like `1 < ''`, `0 > None` or `len <= len` are no longer valid, and e.g. `None < None` raises `TypeError` instead of returning `False`. A corollary is that sorting a heterogeneous list no longer makes sense – all the elements must be comparable to each other. Note that this does not apply to the `==` and `!=` operators: objects of different incomparable types always compare unequal to each other.

---

There are many datatypes that *overload* the comparison operators to do something *different* (dataframes from pandas, numpy's arrays). If the code that you were using did something else, it was because `x` was *not a `list`*, but an instance of some other class with operator `<` overridden to return a value that is not a `bool`; and this value was then handled specially by `x[]` (aka `__getitem__`/`__setitem__`)

Comment: `+False` Hi Perl, hey JavaScript, how y'all doing?

Comment: @cat in Javascript, Perl, it converts the value as number. In Python it is for `UNARY_POSITIVE` opcode that calls the `__pos__`

Comment: I think you meant `__setitem__` instead of `__getitem__` in your last section. Also I hope you don't mind that my answer was inspired by that part of your answer.

Comment: No, I meant and was thinking of `__getitem__` though equally could have been `__setitem__` and `__delitem__`

Answer (score 9):

This has one more use: code golf. Code golf is the art of writing programs that solve some problem in as few source code bytes as possible.

```
return(a,b)[c<d]
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
if c < d:
    return b
else:
    return a
```

except that both a and b are evaluated in the first version, but not in the second version.

`c<d` evaluates to `True` or `False`.
`(a, b)` is a tuple.
Indexing on a tuple works like indexing on a list: `(3,5)[1]` == `5`.
`True` is equal to `1` and `False` is equal to `0`.

1. `(a,b)[c<d]`
2. `(a,b)[True]`
3. `(a,b)[1]`
4. `b`

or for `False`:

1. `(a,b)[c<d]`
2. `(a,b)[False]`
3. `(a,b)[0]`
4. `a`

There's a good list on the stack exchange network of many nasty things you can do to python in order to save a few bytes. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python

Although in normal code this should never be used, and in your case it would mean that `x` acts both as something that can be compared to an integer and as a container that supports slicing, which is a very unusual combination. It's probably Numpy code, as others have pointed out.

Comment: `Code Golf is the art of writing programs` :')

Comment: Minor nitpick: The bool is not *cast* to an int, it just *is* one (see the other answers)

Answer (score 6):

In general it could mean **anything**. It was already explained what it means if `x` is a `list` or `numpy.ndarray` but in general it only depends on how the comparison operators (`<`, `>`, ...) and also how the get/set-item (`[...]`-syntax) are implemented.

```
x.__getitem__(x.__lt__(2))      # this is what x[x < 2] means!
x.__setitem__(x.__lt__(2), 0)   # this is what x[x < 2] = 0 means!
```

Because:

- `x < value` is equivalent to `x.__lt__(value)`
- `x[value]` is (roughly) equivalent to `x.__getitem__(value)`
- `x[value] = othervalue` is (also roughly) equivalent to `x.__setitem__(value, othervalue)`.

---

This can be customized to do **anything** you want. Just as an example (mimics a bit numpys-boolean indexing):

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __lt__(self, other):
        # You could do anything in here. For example create a new list indicating if that 
        # element is less than the other value
        res = [item < other for item in self.value]
        return self.__class__(res)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0} ({1})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.value)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        # If you index with an instance of this class use "boolean-indexing"
        if isinstance(item, Test):
            res = self.__class__([i for i, index in zip(self.value, item) if index])
            return res
        # Something else was given just try to use it on the value
        return self.value[item]

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        if isinstance(item, Test):
            self.value = [i if not index else value for i, index in zip(self.value, item)]
        else:
            self.value[item] = value
```

So now let's see what happens if you use it:

```
>>> a = Test([1,2,3])
>>> a
Test ([1, 2, 3])
>>> a < 2  # calls __lt__
Test ([True, False, False])
>>> a[Test([True, False, False])] # calls __getitem__
Test ([1])
>>> a[a < 2] # or short form
Test ([1])

>>> a[a < 2] = 0  # calls __setitem__
>>> a
Test ([0, 2, 3])
```

Notice this is just one possibility. You are free to implement almost everything you want.

Comment: I would say using **anything** really is way too general for logically explainable behavior like the accepted answer.

Comment: @PascalvKooten Do you disagree with the "anything" or with the generalized answer? I think it's an important point to make because most _logical behaviour_ in python is just by convention.