# Python list notation, Numpy array notation: predictions[predictions < 1e-10] = 1e-10

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to find out operation applied on list. I have list/array name predictions and and executing following set of instruction.

```
predictions[predictions < 1e-10] = 1e-10
```

This code snippet is from a Udacity Machine Learning assignment that uses Numpy.

It was used in the following manner:

```
def logprob(predictions, labels):
    """Log-probability of the true labels in a predicted batch."""
    predictions[predictions < 1e-10] = 1e-10
    return np.sum(np.multiply(labels, -np.log(predictions))) / labels.shape[0]
```

As pointed out by @MosesKoledoye and various others, it is actually a Numpy array. (Numpy is a Python library)

What does this line do?

Comment: Most probably not a list but a numpy array

Comment: Just to make clear what `predictions` really is: Please provide a snippet showing how `predictions` is defined and provide the output of `type(predictions)`.

Comment: Please clarify (in the body of your question, not in a comment) whether `predictions` is a standard Python list, or a Numpy array, or some other kind of data structure.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye is right. Thank you for the answer

Comment: The proposed duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603042/what-does-xx-2-0-mean-in-python, focuses on possible meanings with Python lists. But it is clear from context and the accepted answer that this is a `numpy` array.  That other question is useful  cross reference, but not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by @MosesKoledoye, `predictions` is most likely a `numpy` array.

A boolean array would then be generated using `predictions < 1e-10`. At all indices where the boolean array set by the condition is `True`, the value will be changed to `1e-10`, ie. 10<sup>-10</sup>.

Example:

```
  >>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]) #define array
  >>> a < 3 #define boolean array through condition
  array([ True,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

  >>> a[a<3]  #select elements using boolean array
  array([1, 2])

  >>> a[a<3] = -1  #change value of elements which fit condition
  >>> a 
  array([-1, -1,  3,  4,  5])
```

The reason this might be done in the code could be to prevent division by zero or to prevent negative numbers messing up things by instead inserting a very small number.

Answer (score 1):

All elements of the array, for which the condition (element < 1e-10) is true, are set to 1e-10. 
Practically you are setting a minimum value.

Comment: This is not what will happen. You compare a list to a float, in the bracket, which creates a type error =/

Comment: @HolyDanna this will work with `numpy` arrays, not vanilla lists

Comment: @jonrsharpe The questions says that `predictions` is a list, not an array.

Comment: @HolyDanna it does say that, but is unlikely to be correct. If it is a list, the answer is indeed that it will cause a TypeError, but in that case I doubt the OP would be asking the question.