# How does comparison between different types work in Python?

Tags: python, list, set, tuples

Why does comparison like : `(2,) < {2}` give `False`, while `[2] < {2}` give `True`?

Comment: This is a Python 2 wart, comparison is done by type's name. [Won't work in Python 3 though](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons).

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384078/why-is-0-true-in-python